# How to achieve a zooming effect on a carousel background using CSS3 and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add a background zooming out effect same as in [this website](http://www.ventaforce.com) carousel.. I cannot figure out a solution for that as new to web-designing.

this is the code for the div I want to apply that effect:

MARKUP:

```
<div class="banner">
        <div class="content block1 animated">
          <h1>Ceramic Directory</h1>
          <span>World's largest Ceramic hub, all the ceramic traders reside here!</span>
          <a href="#">Register now</a>
          <span class="handler">&rarr;</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
     .banner{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url("../images/png.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 700px;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .banner .block1{
    background-color: rgba(256,256,256,0.7);
    margin-top: 10%;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 7%;
    animation-name: fadein;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
  }
  .banner .block1 h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: LatoWebLight;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .banner .block1 span{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: LatoWebHairline;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
  }
  .banner .block1 a{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family: LatoWebMedium;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }

  .banner .block1 .handler{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 105%;
    margin-top: -5%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    width: 20px;
    transition: color 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
    transition: background 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s;
  }
  .banner .block1 .handler:hover{
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(34,34,34,0.5);
    color: white;
  }
```

how did they make that?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The website you mentioned uses a jQuery plugin to animate the header image. You can find the plugin's page [here](https://revolution.themepunch.com/jquery/) and some detailed documentation [here](https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/get-started/#initialising)

If you don't plan on using a plugin, you can achieve the image scalling effect by using CSS3. Same example below:

```css
.test { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.test:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}

.test:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/400");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  </div>
```